Schema Owner cannot grant select access to another user (SQL Developer
I have Oracle sample schemas HR, OE, and SH which are tied to users hr, oe, and sh, respectively.   When I log on as  sh user it automatically has access to all SH schema tables,  just as 'oe' user does to OE schema and hr user to HR schema.   So I am "assuming" that the users are owners of the respective schemas above.
As sh user I am able to successfully  grant 'hr' user  read access to all SH schema tables using the following command:
           GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE to hr

However, when I log in as 'oe' user, though I can access all OE schema tables, I get a 'missing privilege' error when I ran the same SQL command as above to grant read access to hr user.  Error messages are shown below:
Error starting at line : 4 in command -
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO hr
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

Appreciate fellow stackoverflower inputs to fix this grant issue. Also would like to know the correct Oracle SQL to check the owner of a particular schema.
I have SQL Developer with version 21.21.1.204 and "Oracle IDE"  version of 21.21.204.1703.

GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE to hr does not grant privs to objects owned by the user executing the statement. It grants privs to all tables owned by all schemas (except SYS) regardless who runs the statement, and is typically only something a DBA can do. Apparently in your installation SH has DBA-level privs, whereas OE does not.
As of 19c (I haven't seen anything later yet) there is no schema-level privileges built into Oracle (no way to say, "let X see anything owned by Y"). To achieve something somewhat like that you have to define a role, grant select privs on all the tables owned by a given schema to that role, and then grant that role to the users you want to give access to. But if the schema adds additional tables down the road, you'd have to add grants to those tables to the role. That's just how it is.
Maybe someday Oracle will give us schema-level grants. But until then, I would not attempt to use select any table or any of the ANY privs to get around the normal security model.

Looking at Oracle online doc - it looks like oracle 23ai already has that feature - GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE ON SCHEMA <> TO <user>  https://blogs.oracle.com/cloudsecurity/post/schemalevel-privilege-grants-with-database-23c#:~:text=To%20grant%20schema%2Dlevel%20privileges,%2C%20USER_SCHEMA_PRIVS%2C%20and%20SESSION_SCHEMA_PRIVS%20views.   But no, I have not tried it as I don't have this version.

@punsoca, that's great to hear!
